# Spring Boot ManyToMany - StackOverflow - JPA,Hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

In my *Spring Boot* application, I have a class named `User` :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    Long userID;
    ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "admins")
    private List<ClassRoom> classRooms  = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And I have another class named `ClassRoom` :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class ClassRoom {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long classRoomID;
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name ="classroom_admins",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "classroom_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<User> admins = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In my `ClassRoomController` I have a method like this:

```
@PostMapping("/class")
ClassRoom newClassRoom(@RequestBody User user) {
    ClassRoom classRoom=new ClassRoom();
    classRoom.getAdmins().add(user);
    user.getClassRooms().add(classRoom);
    logger.debug(classRoom);
    logger.debug(user);
    return repository.save(classRoom);
}
```

Now I posted **`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"userID\":\"22\" }" http://localhost:8080/class`**

This request and it gives me error, saying : `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

I thing I should use `ToString.Exclude` | `JsonBackReference` | `@JsonManagedReference` or something like this, not sure, which is correct, best, which should I use ?

In my `UserController` :

```
@PostMapping("user/{id}/c")
User addClassRoom(@PathVariable Long id,@RequestBody ClassRoom newClassRoom)
{
    logger.debug(repository.findById(id));
    return repository.findById(id)
            .map(user -> {
                user.getClassRooms().add(newClassRoom);
                newClassRoom.getAdmins().add(user);
                return repository.save(user);
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                return null;
            });
}
```

And I posted this **`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{  }" http://localhost:8080/user/2/c`**

**This created an entry in ClassRoom, But `User` has `[]` `ClassRoom` and `ClassRoom` has `[]` `admins` and the `CLASSROOM_USER` table is empty too.**

**How can I resolve this ?**

Full console [here](https://pastebin.com/1qLi94Bq).

Comment: @buræquete do you have answer to this ? can you help me ?

Comment: Sorry I just saw your mail, is it still problematic today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClassRoom classRoom = new ClassRoom();
classRoom.getAdmins().add(user);
return repository.save(classRoom);
```

Do not set the classRooms for the user. It will be assigned automatically.

Or vice versa, basically just do one assignment as Hibernate will handle the many-to-many relationship data in the tables.

Comment: "org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mua.cse616.Model.User; nested ex
ception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mua
.cse616.Model.User", - now I have this

Comment: set     @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) for the ClassRoom

Comment: "attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.mua.cse616.Model.User.loginCredential]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attem
pted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.mua.cse616.Model.User.loginCredential]" - new error

Comment: maybe     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
to User.userId?

Comment: `User`'s `userID` is coming from a class named `LoginCredential`, now ?

Answer (score 0):

the class room has field admins (List) and each user has field class room.
class room load user and user load class room so StackOverflowError occurred.
u have to use somting like @JsonIgnore annotation in User class on admins field.

Comment: Welcome. If I use `@JsonIgnore`, how would I access those thorough my rest-api ?

Comment: one of ur entity have to see another. if u want both of them access each other u have to use DTO one of them has list the other dont have list. for exmaple UserDTO has List<ClassRoomLightDTO> and UserLightDTO dont. reverse for ClassRoom entity

Comment: So how to do that ? Can you help me with the code ? **As I have never heard of DTO**..

Comment: see this link https://thoughts-on-java.org/dto-projections/ .
many tools do that for u like mapstruct or modelmapper